# When Exception came in my android application How to kill all activity's in my application.

Tags: android

I have one doubt in android development. I have given my doubt bellow. please any one can help me out.

Problem: I have developed one android application in that application some times exception will happen in different screens. When exception will happen I want to clear all sessions and I want kill my all activity's.  is there any any exception handlers is there which can take care of my above requirement.

please let me give the suggestions.

Thanks,
Dhamodhar.E

Comment: Why not run a service to do your work?

Comment: That is what I want to run. which services I want to run to do all this things.

Comment: This is not a good approach because ,in some exceptions its too late to handle. E.g : NullPointeException. You can not handle it and you can not edit your flow when NPE throwns

Answer (score 1):

Place your entire app in a try and put :

```
System.exit(0);
```

in catch(Exception e)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that brutally killing application is a good solution, but this is the way to do it:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

Comment: Where I need to add above line in application like I need to add this line in my all class ?

Comment: Have a public static function somewhere and call it from all catch(Exception ex)

Answer (score 0):

You can catch all uncaught exceptions using:-

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(@NonNull Thread t, @NonNull Throwable e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    });
```